# Comparing two data frames to partial match values

Tags: r

I'm really new to r. But I was wondering if it is possible to compare two data frames. For example, I have a data frame with a column containing the values "peanut_butter", "applesauce", "apple juice"  and another data frame column containing the value "apple", "peanut". Is there a way for me to make a loop such that for every row in the first column, it checks against each row of the second column and if there's a partial match (peanut butter contains peanut) it would create a new column with the name of the match?

Answer (score 2):

We could use `fuzzyjoin`:
It has two functions: `regex_inner_join` and `fuzzy_inner_join` for partial matching strings:

```
library(fuzzyjoin)
df1 %>% 
  regex_inner_join(df2, by = "col1")
```

```
  col1.x        col1.y
  <chr>         <chr> 
1 peanut_butter peanut
2 applesauce    apple 
3 apple juice   apple
```

data:

```
library(tibble)
df1 <- tribble(
  ~col1,
  "peanut"
  "peanut_butter", 
  "applesauce", 
  "apple juice" 
)

df2 <- tribble(
  ~col1,
  "apple", 
  "peanut"
)
```